# How can I extract an inner object from a potentially invalid JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, webclient

I am getting this response from an API

```
{\r\n  \"VAL_VER_ZERO_TURN\" : {\r\n    \"J_ID\" : \"345\",\r\n    \"DIS_CODE\" : \"WV345\"\r\n  }\r\n}
```

I am getting this string as a response of webClient.DownloadString(uri)
But when converting it to JSON, the result is blank.

JsonConvert.PopulateObject(response, rockInfo);

When I tried a hardcoded string (instead of webClient.DownloadString(uri)), it worked

```
response = {\"J_ID\" : \"345\",\r\n    \"DIS_CODE\" : \"WV345\"\r\n  }";
```

What I understood here is its working when I fed it the intern JSON object with leading and trailing newline chars. 
But I don't know how can I extract that internal JSON object out.

Comment: Have you tried `JObject.Parse(response)`, then you can access like a dictionary.

Comment: @CallumLinington It helped, can you post it as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

The changes I made in my code as per your comment;

`var parentNode = JObject.Parse(response);
var VER_DO_ID = res.GetValue("VAL_VER_ZERO_TURN");
response = VER_DO_ID.ToString();`

Comment: Why negative votes??? I am new to .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JObject.Parse(response)` to access the different objects as if you were traversing a dictionary.

```
var jobject = JObject.Parse(response);

var abc = jobject["VAL_VER_ZERO_TURN"];
```

You can keep drilling down into each result.

Comment: Can you please undo the downvote (if you can) as you know its a legit questions am being a newbie on C# and .NET.

Comment: I can't undo the downvote - I never voted on the question

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to convert the Json to Class ([json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)) and use *JsonConvert.PopulateObject* to read the inner object. Below is the sample code.

```
    public class VALVERZEROTURN
    {
        public string J_ID { get; set; }
        public string DIS_CODE { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public VALVERZEROTURN VAL_VER_ZERO_TURN { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string response = "{\r\n  \"VAL_VER_ZERO_TURN\" : {\r\n    \"J_ID\" : \"345\",\r\n    \"DIS_CODE\" : \"WV345\"\r\n  }\r\n}";
        RootObject rockInfo = new RootObject();
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(response, rockInfo);

        Console.WriteLine($"J_ID: {rockInfo.VAL_VER_ZERO_TURN.J_ID}, DIS_CODE: {rockInfo.VAL_VER_ZERO_TURN.DIS_CODE} ");
    }
```